# Ubuntu 16: Neither wired nor wireless adapter can be detected

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, networking, drivers

I recently purchased a new Intel NUC (nuc7i5bnh). I installed Ubuntu 16, but it seems no wired or wireless adapters can be detected. When I type `ifconfig` in the terminal, it shows

```
lrg@14:~$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2513 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2513 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:184265 (184.2 KB)  TX bytes:184265 (184.2 KB)
```

But when I type `lshw -C network`, it seems the adapters are there.

```
lrg@14:~$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dc100000-dc101fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       version: 21
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dc200000-dc21ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

I have the same problem when installing Ubuntu 14. However, if I install Ubuntu 18, everything works fine.

Because of certain software compatibility issues, I prefer to use Ubuntu 16 or 14.

Is there any workaround for this problem?